# Service in ROSJAVA. How to start a ServiceServer

Tags: ros, service, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have the problem of generating a service with ros java. I ended up with modifying the pubsub example. I read the javadoc and I ended at the node.newServiceServer part. I started to write my first service with empty request and empty response.

```
  ServiceServer<org.ros.message.std_msgs.Empty, org.ros.message.std_msgs.Empty> server = node.newServiceServer("callme",)
```

According to the javadoc, the params are

- Type Parameters:
- RequestType - type for the request
- ResponseType - type for the response
- Parameters:
- serviceName - the name of the service
- serviceType - the type of the service (e.g. "test_ros/AddTwoInts")
- responseBuilder - called for every request to build a response

Now I am lost. What is the serviceType and what the responseBuilder??????
Can anyone complete my simple line if I want to have a simple service printing "hello world" if the service /callme is called? Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12836/service-in-rosjava.-how-to-start-a-serviceserver/) by [Markus Eich](https://answers.ros.org/users/1686/markus-eich/) on ROS Answers with karma: 202 on 2012-02-01

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The class names are all full qualified here, but you could of course import them so that it wouldn't be necessary (making the code more compact).

```
ServiceServer<org.ros.message.std_msgs.Empty, org.ros.message.std_msgs.Empty> server = node.newServiceServer(
    "callme", "std_srvs/Empty",
    new ServiceResponseBuilder<org.ros.service.std_srvs.Empty.Request, org.ros.service.std_srvs.Empty.Response>() {
      @Override
      public org.ros.service.std_srvs.Empty.Response build(org.ros.service.std_srvs.Empty.Request request) throws ServiceException {
        org.ros.service.std_srvs.Empty.Response response = new org.ros.service.std_srvs.Empty.Response();
        // ...
        return response;
      }
    };
});
```

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-02-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Markus Eich](https://answers.ros.org/users/1686/markus-eich/) on 2012-02-13**:
I imported org.ros.service.*. But the problem is that I cannot resolve org.ros.service.std_srvs.Empty.Response or org.ros.service.std_srvs.Empty.Response. How can I generate and import this messages? The only part I can find is org.ros.service.roscpp... but no ros.service.std_srvs. Any ideas?

**Comment by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) on 2012-02-20**:
Did you add a dependency on std_srvs to your manifest.xml? After adding the dependency, you'll also need to run rosmake.

**Comment by [Markus Eich](https://answers.ros.org/users/1686/markus-eich/) on 2012-02-21**:
Yes, That solved the problem. Thanx,